# ERROR: (gcloud.endpoints.services.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: ERROR: unknown location: Cannot convert to service config

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I am in the process of generating the CloudEndpoints for my APIs built on AppEngine Std Env JDK8 with Guice, and I am working on OSX.

Following the tutorial I’ve:

1. added my prj. ID to my `pom.xml`
2. run `mvn endpoints-framework:openApiDocs`
3. run `gcloud endpoints services deploy target/openapi-docs/openapi.json`

Steps 1 and 2 succeed whereas 3 fails with the message:

`ERROR: (gcloud.endpoints.services.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: ERROR: unknown location: Cannot convert to service config.`

My APIs were not using the `issuers` attribute, for example:

```
issuers = {
                @ApiIssuer(
                        name = "firebase",
                        issuer = "https://securetoken.google.com/<PRJ-ID>",
                        jwksUri = "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com")
}
```

so I tried adding that to each API, but still got the same error.

Help is needed and appreciated :).

Answer (score 2):

This error means there's something wrong with the openapi config file. First, try verifying that it's valid YAML. If it is, then try validating the config with Swagger/OpenAPI tools.

Comment: I use the official swagger editor [here](https://editor.swagger.io/)